# Merge applications in NewRelic

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring

Is there any way to merge two applications (under the same account) in New Relic?

We have an application which has NewRelic monitoring enabled.
The monitor's showing as multiple applications (possibly because there's multiple websites / web.configs configured on this server).
The application's names are exactly the same, but their IDs are different (e.g. with URLs such as below).

- https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/123456/applications/7890123
- https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/123456/applications/4567890

I'm looking for some option to merge these apps such that all historic monitoring from one app is merged with the history of the second app's, and going forwards only one app is displayed.